# SQL : ALTER TABLE Add does not work

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have successfully created a table using:

```
CREATE TABLE "countermeasure" 
(
     "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
     "name" VARCHAR, 
     "description" TEXT check(typeof("description") = 'text'), 
     "probability" DOUBLE, 
     "cost" DOUBLE
)
```

and now I need to add a foreign key to it using:

```
ALTER TABLE "countermeasure" 
(ADD "attack_id" INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY ( "attack_id") REFERENCES attack(id)
)
```

but it complains with the error:

> SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error: ALTER TABLE "countermeasure" (
>   ADD "attack_id" INTEGER  ,
>   FOREIGN KEY ( "attack_id") REFERENCES  attack(id)  ) [ near "(": syntax error ]
>   Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

I am sure I've created the `attack` table well.

Comment: Have you tried removing all double quotes? Or adding a constraint name for foreign key?

Comment: no, but what kind of problem they make?

Comment: Your SQL is inconsistent, you are using double quotes everywhere but ```REFERENCES attack(id)``` so just a suggestion.

Comment: No parens in the `alter table` statement when you're adding a column.

Comment: I'm not sqlite expert, but according to their [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) your parantheses around ADD are not suppose to be there.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, parenthesis around add shouldn't be there. This is the norm generally used for foreign keys

```
    ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN FOREIGNID INT NOT NULL, ADD FOREIGN KEY     
    (FOREIGNID) REFERENCES table2(ID)
```

Comment: I tried this in my phpmyadmin and this gave me the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
 ALTER TABLE table1
 ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_Id)
 REFERENCES table2(P_Id)
```

Answer (score 0):

change (,) for CONSTRAINT

```
ALTER TABLE countermeasure 
ADD attack_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (attack_id) REFERENCES attack(id)
```

or just

```
ALTER TABLE countermeasure 
ADD attack_id INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES attack(id)
```